# migrar query ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mysql a ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET de posgrest

Tags: mysql, postgresql

tengo el siquiente query de MySql

```
          INSERT INTO codigo_postal (d_codigo, d_asenta, d_tipo_asenta, d_mnpio, d_estado, d_ciudad, d_CP, c_estado, c_oficina, c_CP, c_tipo_asenta, c_mnpio, id_asenta_cpcons, d_zona, c_cve_ciudad) VALUES ".$data." ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE d_codigo=VALUES(d_codigo), d_asenta=VALUES(d_asenta),d_tipo_asenta=VALUES(d_tipo_asenta),d_mnpio=VALUES(d_mnpio),d_estado=VALUES(d_estado),d_ciudad=VALUES(d_ciudad),d_CP=VALUES(d_CP),c_estado=VALUES(c_estado),c_oficina=VALUES(c_oficina),c_CP=VALUES(c_CP),c_tipo_asenta=VALUES(c_tipo_asenta),c_mnpio=VALUES(c_mnpio),id_asenta_cpcons=VALUES(id_asenta_cpcons),d_zona=VALUES(d_zona), c_cve_ciudad=VALUES(c_cve_ciudad)";
```

quisiera Migrarlo a posgrest

```
            INSERT INTO codigo_postal (d_codigo, d_asenta, d_tipo_asenta, d_mnpio, d_estado, d_ciudad, d_cp, c_estado, c_oficina, c_cp, c_tipo_asenta, c_mnpio, id_asenta_cpcons, d_zona, c_cve_ciudad) VALUES ".$data." ON CONFLICT (id_codigo_postal) DO UPDATE SET d_codigo=VALUES(d_codigo), d_asenta=VALUES(d_asenta),d_tipo_asenta=VALUES(d_tipo_asenta),d_mnpio=VALUES(d_mnpio),d_estado=VALUES(d_estado),d_ciudad=VALUES(d_ciudad),d_CP=VALUES(d_CP),c_estado=VALUES(c_estado),c_oficina=VALUES(c_oficina),c_CP=VALUES(c_CP),c_tipo_asenta=VALUES(c_tipo_asenta),c_mnpio=VALUES(c_mnpio),id_asenta_cpcons=VALUES(id_asenta_cpcons),d_zona=VALUES(d_zona), c_cve_ciudad=VALUES(c_cve_ciudad)
```

pero Oviamente da error

**ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «(»
LINE 7: ... (id_codigo_postal) DO UPDATE SET  d_codigo=VALUES(d_codigo)...**

COMO LOGRARIA EN POSGRES QUE LAS VARIABLES SE GUARDEN COMO EN MySql. y si no es posible que me pueden asesorar?

Destaco que la variable $data es un .csv del servicio postal mexicano

21395|Villas del Colorado|Residencial|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||30|002|1804|Urbano|02

21395|Los Balcones|Residencial|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||30|002|1831|Urbano|02

21395|Praderas del Sol|Fraccionamiento|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||21|002|2272|Urbano|02

21395|Valle del Puebla|Fraccionamiento|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||21|002|2273|Urbano|02

21395|Valle del Pedregal 7a Sección|Fraccionamiento|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||21|002|2416|Urbano|02

21395|Valle del Pedregal 4a Sección|Fraccionamiento|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||21|002|2419|Urbano|02

21395|Nelson|Parque industrial|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||26|002|0206|Urbano|02

21395|Villa Verde|Fraccionamiento|Mexicali|Baja California|Mexicali|21392|02|21392||21|002|0209|Urbano|02

Comment: *Da error...*  pero, ¿qué error da?

Comment: Listo bro editado es un error de sintaxis. estuve buscando varias formas pero nada..

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 7?  ¿Qué hay dentro de `$data`? ¿Estás usando PHP?

Comment: la data es ese .scv mexicano en mysql corre perfecto. pero  en posgrest me saca el error DO UPDATE SET d_codigo=VALUES(d_codigo) a partir de aca

Comment: Que yo sepa, tú no puedes usar una consulta usando `$data` en postgresql directamente. Te pregunté si estabas usando PHP y no me dices nada al respecto. Pregunto de nuevo, ¿la consulta de ejecuta desde PHP o directamente en postgresql?

Comment: claro claro es desde PHP con CODEIGNITER 3 disculpa si no lei todas las preguntas.